# ReferenceError: dragEvent is not defined", source

Tags: vite, electron-react

I built a project that involved Electron+React+vite, and launched the developer tool locally through OpenDevTools. Every time I switch between tabs, such as when switching from network to console, the vscode terminal will report an error: [10400:0129/203820.666] "ReferenceError: dragEvent is not defined", source: (0)

My code does not define or call dragEvent, I don't know why this error is reported

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/41007

Answer (score 0):

This was an upstream issue in Chrome which has since been fixed (and will eventually make its way into Electron):

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/5067599